How did the Jiva ended up in this material cosmos?
Hare Krsna, I am seeking an answer to the question on how has the Jiva ended up in this material cosmos?
In some sources, it is mentioned that the Jiva-atma is eternally present in Vaikuntha as an energy of the Param-atma. And it once developed a rebellious outlook of being independent from the Param-atma and thus ended up here in the material world which is designed by the Supreme and under the influence of Maya, the Jiva can have the illusion of being in control.
Other sources have mentioned that not even a leaf can fall from Vaikuntha. Hence, we are not fallen souls.
Are there any scriptural references to why the Jiva has ended up in the material world?
Hari Om Tat Sat.

Too many conflicting articles on the web on this topic. This can't be truly comprehended without realization of the self. Suggest listening to this audio by Premanandji till the end. youtube.com/watch?v=52yeXQC1Vm8 The soul certainly doesn't fall down from the chidananda or completely spiritual planets such as Vaikuntha where there's no presence of maha-maya to bewilder the souls, but only yoga-maya.

If jiva has fallen from vaikuntha then what is guarantee that it will not fall again?
I myself have pondered over the question of cause of bondage for a long time..after months of painful research i found an answer in Madhva sampradaya...I was given vedic reference by an eminent scholar..i dont remember it now..
The gist is..each soul has its own intrinsic unique swarupa,ojas and bala it is covered by ajnana which is cause of bondage...it is encased in linga deha/subtle body since anadi or beginningless time....no one put jiva in material world it is in bondage since anadi..when the soul realizes god its ajnana vanishes upto certain extent and when it reaches its highest sadhana level it gets swarupa jnana or cognition of its inner nature..then it goes and bathes in viraja river where the subtle body gets removed and jiva enters Vaikuntha in spiritual form..

Thank you so much for the reply. But won't that put the question that what was the state of jiva before the creation and what will be the state of the jiva after the annihilation of the material world. As described by Krsna in the Gita, this world is temporary but the soul is eternal. I am more curious now.

अव्यक्तादीनि भूतानि व्यक्तमध्यानि भारत |
अव्यक्तनिधनान्येव तत्र का परिदेवना || 28||        O scion of Bharat, all created beings are unmanifest before birth, manifest in life, and again unmanifest on death. So why grieve? Gita 2.28  jivas and souls enter Lord Vishnu's stomach after mahapralaya as he sleeps in the ocean..again at beginning of creation souls come to manifest form and samsara continues..see creation and anhilation is a beginning less process ..just like a infinite spinning wheel it never started probably will never end..

The sense of time elapsing is pure illusion as Reality including the universe is beyond time just like a infinitely spinning wheel which had no starting no end...just those who do sadhana get liberation by Lord's grace
